# Two Docker containers not communicating with each other

Tags: python, django, docker, osrm

I've hosted OSRM server: https://hub.docker.com/r/osrm/osrm-backend/

```
docker run -t -i --network="test-net" -p 5000:5000 -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/indonesia-latest.osrm
```

And its working as I am getting following output when browsing it:

```
{"message":"URL string malformed close to position 1: \"\/\"","code":"InvalidUrl"}
```

The backend is made using Django and the following code is supposed to hit the OSRM server and give the response:

```
BACKEND_HOST = os.getenv('WEB_VRP_BACKEND_HOST', '<ip address of osrm hosted server>')
BACKEND_PORT = os.getenv('WEB_VRP_BACKEND_PORT', '5000')

request = 'http://' + BACKEND_HOST + ':' + BACKEND_PORT + '/table/v1/driving/'
```

Both OSRM and Django is hosted in the same server and same network. The backend is built using docker and run

```
docker run --name vrp-backend --network="test-net" -d -p 9012:8090 vrp-web-django
```

And when i hit the backend with this address and required parameters, i get status:invalid in Postman. The two containers don't seem to be communicating but both are in same network and same server.

```
http://<ip address>/vrp/parse
```

I created the test-net network which is bridged. And docker inspect also shows both container in same network.
What could be the cause? Thanks

Comment: Use OSRM's host (container) name instead of an ip, if the containers are on the same network, they should be able to communicate with each other using each others' host names.

Comment: @nima in that case, i should be able to ping the container name from the other container no? but i can't ping

Comment: Which port are you pinging? You should ping the port inside the container. In this case: `9012:8090` you should ping `8090`, not `9012`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `docker-compose`? You would have an easier time building and running multiple containers with `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`. The yaml file can look something like this:

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  vrp-backend:
    restart: always
    build: path/to/dockerfile # or image: image_name:latest
    command: python3 manage.py runserver
    ports:
      - '9012:8090'
    links:
      - 'osrm:osrm'
  osrm:
    image: osrm/osrm-backend
    command: osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/indonesia-latest.osrm
```

This will create a default network for you and will connect the containers to it.

Comment: And, you can create your own network for these containers in docker compose, it's awesome https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/